# Unable to install mysql-server on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: server, software-installation, mysql, 22.04

I am trying to install mysql-server on ubuntu 22.04 LTS but I am getting the following dpkg error message. How can I fix this issue ?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-ore-8.0
Suggested packages:
 mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 182 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 201995 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_1%3a10.5.15+maria~focal_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (1:10.5.15+maria~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-common (1:10.5.15+maria~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 202191 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 194: /usr/share/mysql- 
common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Although running the command `mysqld -V` command produce the following output -

> /usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Executing the command `sudo service mysql start` produces the following error code -

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.

Answer (score 13):

Reposting my answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412531/issue-with-installation-of-mysql-server-client-on-ubuntu-22-04-ltsjammy). I was able to resolve this issue on Ubuntu 22.04 using [arief21's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13529905/arief21) solution to a [similar problem on 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564442/4364151), which itself was copied from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/completely-uninstall-mysql-server).

### Overview

It seems that the problem comes from some partial initialization remaining in the filesystem from the first, failed installation. So the solution is basically to make sure to clear out everything that was added or modified during the failed install attempts.

I didn't have time to dive much deeper, so I don't know precisely which files are to blame, but if anyone can offer more insight, please comment below for future readers who need a more delicate solution.

### Purge Relevant Packages

- Make sure MySQL is not running:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

- Then purge all of the MySQL packages:

```bash
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

- Then delete all of the MySQL files:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

- Finally clean all packages that are not needed:

```bash
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

- And it never hurts to do a reboot before moving on

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Now with any lingering configuration cruft culled, you should be able to run the install command again.

### MySQL Apt Package Notes

I also read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310590/565842) that some people are experiencing problems with installation of the [`mysql-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server) on Jammy, recommending instead to install the specific [`mysql-server-8.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server-8.0) and [`mysql-server-core-8.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server-core-8.0) packages. Not 100% sure of the truth of this, as I didn't try the `mysql-server` metapackage again after a full purge.

```bash
sudo apt install mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer. One of the most common reasons for repeated failures to install is detritus left over from earlier attempts.

Comment: Well, This answer helped, I had to add one step, which was `systemctl stop exim4` and `systemctl disable exim4`. It took me ages to get ride of a sick myql-server installation.

Comment: - Also check for any broken service link (`/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service `)

- Remove any MariaDB stuff (`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep maria`)
- My experience may help [here](https://blog.kesavan.info/2024/03/03/fix-for-mysql-8x-installation-failure-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Answer (score 4):

You need at least 1 GB of RAM to install MySQL server.
I try install MySQL server with the cheapest instance of DO and it keeps failing. Turns out MySQL server need at least 1 GB to operate. Hope this helps.

Comment: I spent an hour running all sorts of commands on a 512MB droplet with not indication as to why this was failing. Upgraded to 1gb, and everything worked fine. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: man lol this is the correct answer. digitalocean was giving me problems haha

Comment: The same issue, I was trying to Build a docker image on a DigitalOcean "Droplet" (VM) that only had 512Mb of RAM, bumped it upto a1Gb and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue since I had installed the newest MariaDB version from 3rd party repos.

This line in your output gives a hint to the issue:

```
/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
```

When trying to remove/purge the package `mysql-common` apt claims dependencies of many other application packages.

**Solution**

- Remove the *mysql-server* package `apt remove mysql-server mysql-server-8.0` Remove any remaining *mariadb-server* packages as well.
- Remove any 3rd party repos from MariaDB.

  - Use *Synaptic* GUI package manager *or*
  - Manually edit the files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder and comment out the lines by a preceeding `#` character *or*
  - rename/move/delete file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
- Update apt repo system `apt update`
- Downgrade the *mysql-common* package to the Ubuntu version.

  - Use Synaptic GUI package manager *or*
  - List all availabel sources/versions `apt -a show mysql-common` and downgrade to the Ubuntu package version `sudo apt install mysql-common=<VERSION>` *or*
  - Use *aptitude* CLI package manager and try to remove the *mysql-server* package. *aptitude* interactively provides multiple solutions to resolve conflicts and dependencies. Deny all poposals saying 'no' until you find *downgrade mysql-common to* your desired version.
- Reinstall the *mysql-server* package `apt install mysql-server`