# Issue installing mysql in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg, mysql

I am new to Ubuntu and I have been trying to install mysql on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS -hosted on a virtualbox but I keep on getting the same message regardless of what I try. I have tried to uninstall mysql completely and re-install it using the methods proposed by @aquilla <[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405475/unable-to-install-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts)>. I tried to add resources to /etc/apt/resources.list . I even tried to upgrade the OS from 20.04 to 22.04 but none of them have worked so far. This error message is what comes up. I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
● *mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: oom-kill) since Fri 2023-02-17 09:55:40 UTC; 55ms ago
    Process: 3089 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3097 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 3097 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
        CPU: 1.028s
Feb 17 09:55:40 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Feb 17 09:55:40 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 17 09:55:40 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Feb 17 09:55:40 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Feb 17 09:55:40 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 1.028s CPU time.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0*
```

Comment: Did you look up what `Failed with result 'oom-kill'` means?

Comment: Yeah how much base memory did you allocate to the VM?

Comment: I had allocated 40GB and so far I have used only 11.53GB.

Comment: Thank you both for directing me to the base memory; that was the main problem all along. When I increased the base memory of the VM, the problem was solved.