# Problem while installing MySQL

Tags: 22.04, mysql

Ubuntu 22.04

While installing MySQL this information come up

```
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for luis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.28-0ubuntu4) but 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
luis@l-System-luisj:~$
```

As I don’t understand ask some one to help with this
Thank you
I did sudo apt update and installed it again but still something wrong  some broken packages
I need  advise on how to fix this.

```
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for luis: 
Hit:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bablu-boy/nutty/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jentiger-moratai/mediatools/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done                       
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.28-0ubuntu4) but 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ 
``I did sudo apt update twice but end up the same, can it be something with wrong
Ubuntu itself?.

luis@l-System-luisj:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.28-0ubuntu4) but 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
luis@l-System-luisj:~$ `
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` first?  It looks like you might have some out of date information about your repositories on system which is resulting in the conflict.

Comment: try to use `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt update`

Comment: @BlackSnow I guess you mean `upgrade` for the second command.

Comment: Does this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405475/unable-to-install-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts) answer your question?