# Issue with installation of MYSQL server/client on UBUNTU 22.04 LTS(Jammy)

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies, 22.04

I am trying to install mysql server on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but couldnt do that it says unmet dependencies and i tried installing the required dependencies but it didnt work.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installable
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: `you have requested an impossible situation` generally occurs when there is more to the story that you have so far revealed. Often it includes non-Ubuntu or wrong-version sources that are still cluttering your system. Clean up your previous attempts, and then it will install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. If you don't have `aptitude` on your machine yet, get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then run:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

In the prompt, you should not accept the first solution (enter `n`) to force reload of dependencies.

Comment: mysql: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
mysql: [ERROR] Stopped processing the 'includedir' directive in file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 29.
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!

Comment: I tried the same but it shows this

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reason why this happens is because you have some old MySQL or MariaDB packages installed on your system. MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL and both use the same library names and files (both in `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mysql/my.conf`). Check this post: [Why does Ubuntu prohibit installing both MySQL and MariaDB via apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1428670/1157209) for more details. You can do some clean up and try to install the MySQL server again.

To check if this is your problem, run:

```
apt list --installed | grep mysql
apt list --installed | grep mariadb
```

Look for `mysql-server`, `mysql-client`, `mariadb-server`, `mariadb-client` and other similar packages.

If you want to install MySQL, you will have to uninstall these. You can remove them manually one by one or use `apt` with wildcard(`*`) like this:

```
sudo apt remove mysql*
sudo apt remove mariadb*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Install MySQL Server:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Answer (score -1):

### Overview

It seems that the problem comes from some partial initialization remaining in the filesystem from the first, failed installation. So the solution is basically to make sure to clear out everything that was added or modified during the failed install attempts.

I didn't have time to dive much deeper, so I don't know precisely which files are to blame, but if anyone can offer more insight, please comment below for future readers who need a more delicate solution.

I was able to resolve this issue on Ubuntu 22.04 as described below, using [arief21's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13529905/arief21) solution to a [similar problem on 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67564442/4364151), which itself was copied from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/completely-uninstall-mysql-server).

### Purge Relevant Packages

- Make sure MySQL is not running:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

- Then purge all of the MySQL packages:

```bash
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

- Then delete all of the MySQL files:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

- Finally clean all packages that are not needed:

```bash
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

- And it never hurts to do a reboot before moving on

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Now with any lingering configuration cruft culled, you should be able to run the install command again.

### MySQL Apt Package Notes

I also read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310590/565842) that some people are experiencing problems with installation of the [`mysql-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server) on Jammy, recommending instead to install the specific [`mysql-server-8.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server-8.0) and [`mysql-server-core-8.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mysql-server-core-8.0) packages. Not 100% sure of the truth of this, as I didn't try the `mysql-server` metapackage again after a full purge.

```bash
sudo apt install mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @aquila I followed your steps but still get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-server-core-8.0 but 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @CodeConnoisseur do you know if you actually have packages  held at a specific version? 

`apt-mark showhold` will list any held packages.

Comment: I had to actually purge all of mysql from my ubuntu installation then re-install from scratch.